# Docker: chmod: cannot access 'chmod': No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, shell, docker, sh

I am building a **Rails** application on **Ubuntu** 18.04 and I trying to set up the deployment of the application using docker.

I have 2 entrypoint files:

- docker/entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh
- docker/entrypoints/sidekiq-entrypoint.sh

Usually, to make the files executable, I have to run the commands below in my host machine terminal:

```
chmod +x docker/entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh
chmod +x docker/entrypoints/sidekiq-entrypoint.sh
```

However, I would like to make this possible in the Dockerfile, without having to always do it on the host machine's terminal.

For this, I added the command below in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN chmod +x docker/entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh \
    chmod +x docker/entrypoints/sidekiq-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker/entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

But then I run into this error:

> chmod: cannot access 'chmod': No such file or directory
>
> chmod: cannot access '+x': No such file or directory
>
> ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x docker/entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh     chmod +x docker/entrypoints/sidekiq-entrypoint.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1

I have tried a few solutions, but none has worked so far. Any form of help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: You need some punctuation between the two commands, `RUN chmod ... && chmod ...`.  The backslash-newline inserts whitespace but doesn't actually terminate the first `chmod` command.

Comment: while your solution solves the problem, there was an error in the command. It should be `chmod -x file && chmod -x another file` in your case the commands reads `chmod +x file1 chmod +x file2` since there are no chmod or +x files, it'll simply fail

Comment: @Stefano, I think the command should be `chmod +x file1 chmod +x file2` and not `chmod -x file && chmod -x another file` since I am making the files executable. It will be  `chmod -x file && chmod -x another file` if I am revoking the permissions for the files.

Comment: Thank you @DavidMaze, can you elaborate more on your answer with a clearer example.

Comment: it was a typo. I meant +x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here's how I solved it**:

Simply change the command in the `Dockerfile` from:

```
RUN chmod +x docker/entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh \
    chmod +x docker/entrypoints/sidekiq-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker/entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

to this:

```
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/docker/entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh"] \
    ["chmod", "+x", "/docker/entrypoints/sidekiq-entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker/entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Also, endeavour to see that you copy/copied the `docker-entrypoint.sh` to your working directory. Any of the following will do it:

```
# Copy other project files
COPY . ./

# Docker init
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "docker-entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**OR**

```
# Copy docker entrypoint file
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh ./

# Docker init
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "docker-entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

OR

```
# Copy docker entrypoint file
COPY /docker/docker-entrypoint.sh ./docker/docker-entrypoint.sh

# Docker init
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "docker/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**Note**: This depends on the location of your `docker-entrypoint.sh` and where you was to copy it to.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**